# Trouble querying from realm: Initialiser error

Tags: ios, realm, swift2

I am trying to query the `name` field from my Realm database but I keep getting thrown this error

> Initialiser for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Results<(Particulars)>' (aka 'Results')

This is my code

```
import Foundation
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Users {
private var _name: String!
private var _email: String!
private var _userId: Int!
private var _profilePicture: String!
private var _username: String!

let realm = try! Realm()

var name: String {
    _name = getName()
    return _name
}

var email: String {
    _email = getEmail()
    return _email
}

func getName () {

    guard let userName = Data.sharedInstance.userName  else { print("Empty username"); return }

    if let name = realm.objects(Particulars).filter("username == '\(userName)'"){
        return name
    }

}

func getEmail () {

    guard let userName = Data.sharedInstance.userName  else { print("Empty username"); return }

    if let email = realm.objects(Particulars).filter("username == '\(userName)'"){
        return email
    }

}
```

[image: realm query errors]

This is my realm database:

[image: realm table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1) `Realm.objects()` returns a `Results` object (the same as an array) that contains zero or more objects of the type you searched for. If you want to get just the first object returned from that query, add `.first` at the end, after `.filter`.

2) After getting the first object, it'll still be of type `Particulars`. After that, you'll need to actually access the property you're after (i.e. `name` or `email`)

So for example:

```
func getEmail() {

   if let particular = realm.objects(Particulars).filter("username == '\(userName)'").first {
      return particular.email
   }
}
```

Let me know if you need any more clarification. :)

Comment: Hi @TiM I'm getting a 'unexpected non void return value in void function' error at my return line. Do you know how I can fix it?